# IoT Edge System and Custom Module failed runtime status

Tags: android, azure, docker, azure-iot-edge

Following [this guide](https://azure.github.io/Vision-AI-DevKit-Pages/docs/Get_Started/#configure-your-camera-to-connect-to-azure-as-an-iot-edge-device) I am setting up my Vision AI DevKit with Azure. The guide really just has me enter some wifi credentials and past a connection string in the setup portal for my edge device in Azure. I've completed the guide in full, using my mobile hotspot for wifi, but noticed for the next step of Connecting to the live RTSP video stream on the camera from this address `rtsp://<IP address>:8900/live` I need to have a custom module deployed to my device.

So I'm following this [custom module](https://azure.github.io/Vision-AI-DevKit-Pages/docs/Deploy_Model_IoT_Hub/#select-your-vision-ai-devkit-hardware-in-the-azure-portal) guide to do so and in the Azure portal I confirm both the edge system modules and edge custom module are reported on the device, but I'm now running into some hard to debug runtime errors for both the `edgeHub` and `VisionSample`.

[image]

Below I am using [`adb`](https://azure.github.io/Vision-AI-DevKit-Pages/docs/Review_logs/) to get some more details for the runtime errors on the

`adb shell docker logs -f edgeHub`

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Permission denied
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TcpTransportListener.OnListen()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportListener.Listen(Action`2 callback)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportListener.OnListen()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportListener.Listen(Action`2 callback)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportListener.OnListen()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportListener.Listen(Action`2 callback)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Amqp.AmqpProtocolHead.StartAsync() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Amqp/AmqpProtocolHead.cs:line 80
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service.Program.MainAsync(IConfigurationRoot configuration) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service/Program.cs:line 97
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service.Program.Main() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service/Program.cs:line 30
[2019-06-04 20:17:25 +00:00]: Starting Edge Hub
[06/04/2019 08:17:25.766 PM] Edge Hub Main()
[06/04/2019 08:17:28.961 PM] Found intermediate certificates: [CN=iotedged workload ca:09/02/2019 17:29:21],[CN=Test Edge Device CA:09/02/2019 17:29:21],[CN=Test Edge Owner CA:09/02/2019 17:29:21]
2019-06-04 20:17:31.254 +00:00 [INF] - Created persistent store at /tmp/edgeHub
2019-06-04 20:17:31.401 +00:00 [INF] - Created device scope identities cache
2019-06-04 20:17:31.450 +00:00 [INF] - Starting refresh of device scope identities cache
2019-06-04 20:17:31.486 +00:00 [INF] - Starting Edge Hub
2019-06-04 20:17:31.487 +00:00 [INF] - 
        █████╗ ███████╗██╗   ██╗██████╗ ███████╗
       ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔════╝
       ███████║  ███╔╝ ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
       ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
       ██║  ██║███████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
       ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

 ██╗ ██████╗ ████████╗    ███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ███████╗
 ██║██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝    ██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔════╝ ██╔════╝
 ██║██║   ██║   ██║       █████╗  ██║  ██║██║  ███╗█████╗
 ██║██║   ██║   ██║       ██╔══╝  ██║  ██║██║   ██║██╔══╝
 ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║       ███████╗██████╔╝╚██████╔╝███████╗
 ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝       ╚══════╝╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝

2019-06-04 20:17:31.491 +00:00 [INF] - Version - 1.0.7.1.22377503 (f7c51d92be8336bc6be042e1f1f2505ba01679f3)
2019-06-04 20:17:31.500 +00:00 [INF] - Loaded server certificate with expiration date of "2019-09-02T17:29:21.0000000+00:00"
2019-06-04 20:17:31.556 +00:00 [INF] - Created new message store
2019-06-04 20:17:31.561 +00:00 [INF] - Started task to cleanup processed and stale messages
2019-06-04 20:17:32.032 +00:00 [INF] - Initialized twin manager v1.
2019-06-04 20:17:32.066 +00:00 [INF] - Initializing configuration
2019-06-04 20:17:32.129 +00:00 [INF] - New device connection for device edge-test-vai/$edgeHub
2019-06-04 20:17:32.364 +00:00 [INF] - Attempting to connect to IoT Hub for client edge-test-vai/$edgeHub via AMQP...
2019-06-04 20:17:36.736 +00:00 [WRN] - Encountered an error while refreshing the device scope identities cache. Will retry the operation in some time...
2019-06-04 20:17:59.513 +00:00 [WRN] - Error creating cloud connection for client edge-test-vai/$edgeHub
```

`adb shell docker logs -f VisionSample`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=1080): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5715a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_iotcc_sdk/sdk/main.py", line 178, in <module>
    main()
  File "./python_iotcc_sdk/sdk/main.py", line 42, in main
    with CameraClient.connect(ip_address=ip_addr, username=username, password=password) as camera_client:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/app/python_iotcc_sdk/sdk/camera.py", line 108, in connect
    ipc_provider.connect()
  File "/app/python_iotcc_sdk/sdk/ipcprovider.py", line 223, in connect
    response = mysession.post(url,data=payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 572, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 524, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=1080): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5715a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
Error: Time:Tue Jun  4 19:53:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c Func:wait_for_connection Line:385 Failure: connect failure 111.
Error: Time:Tue Jun  4 19:53:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c Func:socketio_open Line:769 wait_for_connection failed
Error: Time:Tue Jun  4 19:53:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c Func:on_underlying_io_open_complete Line:760 Invalid tlsio_state. Expected state is TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_UNDERLYING_IO.
Error: Time:Tue Jun  4 19:53:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/c-utility/adapters/tlsio_openssl.c Func:tlsio_openssl_open Line:1258 Failed opening the underlying I/O.
Error: Time:Tue Jun  4 19:53:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/umqtt/src/mqtt_client.c Func:mqtt_client_connect Line:1000 Error: io_open failed
Error: Time:Tue Jun  4 19:53:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:SendMqttConnectMsg Line:2122 failure connecting to address qcs605-32.
```

Comment: Hi did you find a way to resolve this error???

Comment: I have not, but would like some additional feedback from others.